# Has Mr. Zero ever been hit with his own ice-gun?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, dc-animated-universe, mr-freeze

The question jumped in my mind as I rewatched Joel Schumacher’s *[Batman and Robin (1997)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_%26_Robin_(film))* where, at an early scene of the film, Batman grabs the ice-gun pointing it at Mr. Freeze but doesn't have time to shoot.

[image: Still image from Batman and Robin (1997)]

Also, in the Toys "R" Us Replica Edition (1997) of the original DC comic Batman #121 *The Ice Crimes of Mr. Zero!* (1959), where Mr. Zero (after known as Mr. Freeze) first appeared, it looks to me that at the end of the story, Mr. Zero was attempting to reach his ice-gun, not to defend himself against Batman and Robin, but to shoot himself with the weapon's ice gas in order to counteract the deadly effects of the steam bath in which he was enveloped.

[image: image from the DC comic Batman #121 (1959)]

Most of us are aware that, as a result of an accident in his laboratory while experimenting with a concentrated freezing solution, Mr. Zero's physiology was altered in such a way that he was obliged to live in conditions below zero degrees Celsius.

I'm asking because, in case that happened in the DC Universe, wouldn’t be interesting to know if Mr. Freeze can be overly frozen or can manage to resist that which changed forever his life?

Comment: Mr Freeze got frozen to a wall in DETECTIVE COMICS (2016) ISSUE #1056. He suffered no adverse consequences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although it isn't Mr. Freeze himself, in *[Batman: The Animated Series](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Batman:_The_Animated_Series)*, in the episode [Deep Freeze](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Freeze), [Grant Walker](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Grant_Walker) asked to be inflicted by the same stuff Dr. Victor Fries himself endured which turned him into Mr. Freeze; the reason being that it also prevented him from ageing, making him immortal.

By the end of the episode, Mr. Freeze decided to side with Batman and stop whatever madness Mr. Walker had planned to do. He shot his freezing gun at the man (who was wearing a suit similar to Freeze).

It didn't directly affect him, but what it did was trapping him inside an ice prison, which then went down sinking. And since the man was as immortal as Mr. Freeze was, it meant he will remain there for the rest of eternity.

The scene where Mr. Freeze shoots his freezing gun at the man:

And the scene where the man, stuck inside solid glass, sinks to the bottom of the sea:

Comment: Because of course we all know that ice sinks in water.

Comment: @DavidW You know, I haven't thought of that but good point

Comment: Depends on how much ice was involved, if the mean density of something encased by ice is greater than water, then it will sink

Comment: Saturday morning cartoons used to be dark!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You wouldn't believe how much the episode _"Growing Pain"_ of this cartoon scarred my mind, even though I was too young to understand what they were saying. A true marvel of art; both the writing and the visual.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Trivia: unlike other cartoons, this one was so _dark_, they actually used black paper, unlike other cartoons of that period which always used white paper.